# подключить кнопки Start | Stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на ссылку "Stop" элементы должны прекратить добавляться
При нажатии на ссылку "Start" элементы должны снова начать добавляться
При запуске программы сделать, чтобы элементы начали добавляться.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
  $("#container").append('<div class="element">'+ numRandom + '</div>');
 }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
 
<a id="start">Start</a> 
<a id="stop">Stop</a>
```

Comment: и в чем конкретно возникла сложность: заводите переменную в которую запишите результат `setInterval`(она нужна для остановки), напишите обработчик события `click` для кнопок, в одном запускаете таймер и запоминаете id в переменную, в другом обработчике останавливаете [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ с [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539079/how-to-start-and-stop-pause-setinterval)

```js
function start() {
  add = setInterval(function() {
   var numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    $("#container").append('<div class="element">'+ numRandom + '</div>');
  }, 1000);
}

start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
 
<a href="#" onclick="start()">Start</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="clearInterval(add)">Stop</a>
```